# Figuring out whether a user stopped scrolling with jQuery's debounce

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a webpage that tracks where a user is on a vertically scrolling webpage. I'm currently listening to the `scroll` event, but that's firing too often. What I'd like to do is listen to something like a `scroll end` event, but that doesn't exist. I've read through a few answers on StackOverflow, including using a timeout, and I think I've decided on using jQuery's `debounce` method to do something like this:

```
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, true, function(){
    $('#scrollMsg').html('SCROLLING!');
} ) );
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, function(){
    $('#scrollMsg').html('DONE!');
} ) );
```

I'm worried that I could still miss some `scroll end` events. It's important to my service that I *always* catch the `end` event so that I can accurately track where the user is on the webpage. Can anyone shed some light on whether this is a valid concern? I've done some cursory testing, but I'm not confident enough to make a call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there will be always a delay between what's the user viewing "which part" of your webpage and the stored information in the DB or where ever you are storing that information in,
and you can't also send a get request whenever he scrolls or move the mouse because this leads to horrendous amount of requests.

so in my opinion you just have to set an interval that suites your requirements to send a 'heart beat' to your server let's say every 5 seconds, which is actually a `json` data includes the current link he is browsing and which part of the page along with any other data you might find it useful such as last activity (you can measure this in many ways: ex. last mouse over `<body>` movement)
this way you well have the chance as will in the future to add any information to that `heart beat` to be delivered to your server and give you more tracking information.